# npm wait.for not working as expected

Tags: node.js, npm

tried the code below as provided in the official site - https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait.for. But not working as expected.

Output:

*before calling test

after calling test

reverse for 216.58.196.142: ["syd15s04-in-f14.1e100.net"]*

Expected output:
*before calling test

reverse for 216.58.196.142: ["syd15s04-in-f14.1e100.net"]

after calling test*

What is that I can do to make it work?

```
var dns = require("dns"), wait=require('wait.for');

function test(){
   var addresses = wait.for(dns.resolve4,"google.com");
   for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
       var a = addresses[i];
       console.log("reverse for " + a + ": " + JSON.stringify(wait.for(dns.reverse,a)));
   }
}
console.log("before calling test");
wait.launchFiber(test); 
console.log("after calling test");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wait.launchFiber(test);
```

Means launch and forget. launchFiber starts a concurrent execution fiber. Inside the fiber you can use wait for, but the fiber is concurrent with the main execution thread.